# android javascript won't work after redirect

Tags: javascript, android, redirect, webview

I'm using `mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this, XXX)` to let java
enter code herescript be executed on a webview.

The problem comes when the web page that I'm browsing sends a redirect. 
I'm able to capture it an display the new URL in the same webview but javascript will not work.

The only solution that I've found is to create a new intent that load the new page on a new Activity.

```
public class QBrowser extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.qbrowser_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {   
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    // BEGIN: THE WORK AROUND I DONT LIKE
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.bcnquark.client.qbrowser.QBROWSER");
            intent.putExtra("URL", url);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            // END:THE WORK AROUND I DONT LIKE
            return true;
        }});


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "XXXX");
    }

    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
}
```